# Running Google I/O 2016 app from source code using Android Studio

Tags: android

I am fairly new to Android development. I decided to build and run the Google I/O application using Android Studio. But it only installs the Map Editor app on the phone and not the full-fledged one. Also, there are 2 Android manifest files - one of the Map editor and the other of the app.
Did someone have the same problem? Moreover, could anyone give a detailed tutorial on how to edit the app? It takes a long for the Gradle to build only to find out that it only compiled the wrong app.

Comment: Where did you get the 2017 app from, their github is still 2016

Comment: I understand the numerical error but did you face the same issue as mine.